# Chef Inspec: undefined local variable or method `aws_region'

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, inspec

I am testing out basic [Chef Inspec](https://www.inspec.io/) code. I am running it from a Mac using the API call:

```
inspec exec sg-disallow-ftp.rb -t aws://
```

Here is the Chef code for the profile:

```
title 'Test AWS Security Groups Across All Regions For an Account Disallow FTP'

control 'aws-multi-region-security-group-ftp-1.0' do

  impact 1.0
  title 'Ensure AWS Security Groups disallow FTP ingress from 0.0.0.0/0.'

  aws_region.region_names.each do |region|
    aws_security_groups(aws_region: region).group_ids.each do |security_group_id|
      describe aws_security_group(aws_region: region, group_id: security_group_id) do
        it { should exist }
        it { should_not allow_in(ipv4_range: '0.0.0.0/0', port: 21) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting this error:

```
×  aws-multi-region-security-group-ftp-1.0: Ensure AWS Security Groups disallow FTP ingress from 0.0.0.0/0.
     ×  Control Source Code Error sg-disallow-ftp.rb:3 
     undefined local variable or method `aws_region' for #<#<Class:0x00007fc35a095158>:0x00007fc356ebd568>
```

Comment: Looks like it's the `aws_region.region_names.each` cannot find anything in scope named `aws_region`. Maybe you're missing a `require` or `gem`?

Comment: So when you say require can you explain I am new to inspec

Answer (score 1):

So finally figured it out I had to run inspect vendor --overwrite in the profile directory and the test executed

Answer (score 0):

seems that you are missing few configurations.

i will assume that you have created an [inspec profile](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/profiles/) named `aws`. you can create a profile by leveraging [`inspec init`](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/cli/)

```sh
$ inspec init profile aws
```

once you created the profile, you need to specify the dependecy on [`inspec-aws`](https://github.com/inspec/inspec-aws) to [use the resources](https://github.com/inspec/inspec-aws#use-the-resources). you will do this in `aws/inspec.yml` file, which will look something like:

```
name: aws
title: InSpec Profile
maintainer: The Authors
copyright: The Authors
copyright_email: you@example.com
license: Apache-2.0
summary: An InSpec Compliance Profile
version: 0.1.0
supports:
  platform: aws
inspec_version: '>= 4.6.9'
depends:
  - name: inspec-aws
    url: https://github.com/inspec/inspec-aws/archive/v1.3.2.tar.gz
```

and you should be ready to go.

you can verify that it works by using `inspec shell` with conjunction of resource packs, like so:

```sh
$ inspec shell --depends aws -t aws://
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate this will give it a shot

Comment: I tried to execute a profile using this command inspec exec rodney-profile -t aws:// and I get this "error/opt/inspec/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:378:in `open_http': 404 Not Found (OpenURI::HTTPError)" I am running version of inspec 4.18.24 on MAC OS. I installed Inspec using brew

Comment: I also tried to run this command and I got inspec shell --depends ${name of profile} -t aws:// and I got this error message No file provider forthe provided path

Comment: So if I run chef inspec from the controls directory I can get a successful run of inspec test.  inspec exec iam.rb -t aws:// and executed fine. But trying to run from a profile doesn't work. inspec exec iam -t aws://  get error 404 Not Found (OpenUIR::HTTPError)

Comment: I try to run a simple testdescribe aws_regions do
  its('region_names') { should include 'eu-west-2' }
end error undefined local variable or method `aws_regions' for #<#<Class:0x00007f9b39f3d780>:0x00007f9b39

Comment: @RodneyBizzell: please read again my answer and pay attention to the details - i did not change my working directory and every command was executed from the root directory. please try my answer above, to verify that it works for you.